# How to paginate when reading large XML file

Tags: php, ajax, domdocument

I am just trying to do a small project for my (very simple) website, my goal is to create an easily searchable list of links with this code but the list I have is very long (500+ entries in an xml) and I would like to limit the results to 5-10

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');
$q=$_GET["q"];
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}
echo $response;
?>
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

use 'while' and if it reached max results, it stops giving results.

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");
$maxresult=10;
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');
$q=$_GET["q"];
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
   while($i < $maxresult) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" .
          $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
          "' target='_blank'>" .
          $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}
echo $response;
?>
```